# How do I select distinct and then perform a multi-insert for each of the distinct results?

Tags: jquery, sql, postgresql, distinct, sql-insert

I want to select all of the distinct `orgId`s in a table and then run this insert query for each of the distinct results into the same table?:

```
INSERT into "ffOrgs" (id, "ffId", "orgId", value, enabled, "createdAt", "updatedAt")
values (uuid_generate_v4(), 1111 , ABC, null, now(), now(), true),
( uuid_generate_v4(), 1001 , ABC, null, now(), now(), true)
( uuid_generate_v4(), 1002 , ABC, null, now(), now(), true)
( uuid_generate_v4(), 1003 , ABC, null, now(), now(), true)
```

For example, let's say the table has 5 unique `orgIds` (ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL, MNO) and for each of those orgs, I want to insert the above set of values. How would you combine the two query?

Comment: where is the value for ffId coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want:

```
insert into fforgs (id, ffid, orgid, value, enabled, createdat, updatedat)
select uuid_generate_v4(), f.ffId, o.orgId, null, now(), true
from (select distinct ffId from ffOrgs) o
cross join (values(1111, 1001, 1002, 1003)) f(orgId)
```

The query selects all distinct `ffId` from the table, then `cross join`s it with a fixed list of `ordId` values. The resulting dataset is inserted.